# Modulus proof with factorials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial, congruences

Prove that $(2p−1)! ≡ p \pmod {\space p^2}$
Hint: $p$ divides ($2p-1)!$

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Another hint: $(p-1)! = -1 \pmod{p}$ (assuming $p$ is prime of curse)

Comment: It's not true. Check $p = 4$.

Answer (score 2):

The case $p=2$ is easy to check by hand, hence we may assume $p>2$.
$$\frac{(2p-1)!}{p}= 1\cdot 2\cdots (p-1)\cdot(p+1)\cdot(p+2)\cdots (2p-1)=\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(p^2-k^2) $$
is equivalent $\!\!\pmod{p}$ to:
$$ (-1)^{p-1}\left[(p-1)!\right]^2 $$
that by Wilson's theorem is $1\pmod{p}$.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give another way. Noticed that $$(p+1)(p+2)....(2p-1)=mp^2+(p-1)!$$ It follows, using Wilson, $$(2p-1)!=(p-1)!p(p+1)(p+2)....(2p-1)=p(pn-1)(mp^2+(p-1)!)=(p^2n-p)(mp^2+pn-1)=Mp^2+p$$

Thus $$(2p−1)! ≡ p \pmod {\space p^2}$$

Comment: Why ?:
$$
\left(2 \times \color{#f00}{4} - 1\right)! = 7! = 5040 = 5036 + \color{#f00}{4} = {5036 \over 16}\,\color{#f00}{4}^{2} + \color{#f00}{4} =
{1259 \over 4}\,\color{#f00}{4}^{2} + \color{#f00}{4}
$$